# How to run lauch4j in command line?

Tags: launch4j

I am newbie to launch4j.I want to create exe file using launch4j.
I have followed this link for [lauch4j](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/docs.html) tutorial. 
Now,i want to create exe file in command line using launch4j?
I have tried following command but its not working.

```
>launch4j.exe sample.jar
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To run it in console mode you need to use `launch4jc.exe` (not `launch4j.exe`) and feed `config.xml` to it as a parameter.

[Docs](http://launch4j.sourceforge.net/docs.html):

> To wrap a jar in console mode use **launch4jc.exe** and specify the configuration file.

Comment: Are you sure you've set the correct file path in `<jar>` tag in your config file? If yes - please provide more info (config file, more info about file you are trying to wrap, etc).

Comment: Thanks Loy.launch4jc.exe config.xml execute this cmd and got following error.launch4j: Application jar doesn't exist.but i have jar in this place.Is this need to specify the jar in cmd?